# Display a price with correct currency symbol based on currency code such as 'USD' in .NET

Tags: .net, flutter, internationalization

I am working on an online marketplace app that needs to display a price in the correct format for various countries. My question is how to display the price in the correct format based on the currency symbol such as EUR, JPN, USD, etc.

To explain a bit on the app, sellers in different countries have different prices in different currencies. For example, a seller in Spain sells an item in EUR. A seller in Japan sells an item in JPN. Users pick these currency symbols EUR, JPN, USD, etc. when they list an item.

In .NET, I can use .ToString("C", cultureInfo) to get the correct currency symbol and the correct number format. This method works great if the user picks the culture code such as es-es, ja-jp, etc. because these culture code can be used to create CultureInfo object above. The ToString("C", cultureInfo) does not work when the user's starting point is currency symbols such as EUR.

.NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gkL9Db

```
// Display '4.5' with currency formats from various countries.
decimal price = 4.50M;
foreach (CultureInfo cultureInfo in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures))
{
    string formattedPrice = price.ToString("C", cultureInfo);
    Console.WriteLine(cultureInfo.ToString() + ": " + formattedPrice);
}
```

Output samples around Spanish

es-AR: $ 4,50
es-BO: Bs4,50
es-BR: R$4.50
es-BZ: $4.50
es-CL: $5
es-CO: $ 4,50F
es-CR: ₡4,50F
es-CU: $4.50F
es-DO: RD$4.50
es-EA: 4,50 €
es-EC: $4,50
es-ES: 4,50 €
es-GQ: FCFA5
es-GT: Q4.50
es-HN: L4.50
es-IC: 4,50 €
es-MX: $4.50
es-NI: C$4.50
es-PA: B/.4.50
es-PE: S/ 4.50
es-PH: 4,50 ₱

Is there a good way to display correct currency format based on currency symbol? The .NET code runs on the cloud and the client is Flutter. Any suggestions on Flutter side would be appreciated as well.

Comment: Have you tried intl package? https://pub.dev/packages/intl#number-formatting-and-parsing

Comment: @Rahul, thanks! I do use the intl package, but never looked at the  NumberFormat.symbols. The symbols object has property 'DEF_CURRENCY_CODE', which returns 'EUR'. So, I should be able to create a mapping table between 'EUR' and es_ES and use it with .NET code on the server side.

Comment: Actually, my test code var f0 = NumberFormat('###.0#', 'es_AR');
print(f0.symbols.DEF_CURRENCY_CODE); returns "EUR" when I am expecting 'ARS' (Argentine Peso). Not sure if this is a bug in the intl package.